# How to obtain AD oauth token to authenticate database connection in an rmarkdown document?

Tags: javascript, r, oauth-2.0, r-markdown, azure-ad-msal

I have a bit of a strange question. I have built shiny apps in the past where I have been able to use the JavaScript MSAL library to grab oauth tokens to authenticate a db connection by using it as a Shiny input value.

I am trying to do something similar in an RMarkdown report, but as js libraries don't load as nicely in rmarkdown - how would I do something similar? Most options that I've seen (httr2, AzureAuth) requires the client secret but I don't have that.

I only have the tenant ID, app/client ID, and scopes. Is there anyway to grab an AD oauth token with the information that I have in an rmarkdown script that doesn't use the MSAL library?

Here is my implementation of the MSAL solution in a minimal script if anyone does think it is possible:

````
/```{r}

library(htmltools)
library(shiny)
 htmltools::tagList(
   htmltools::tags$script(src = "https://alcdn.msauth.net/browser/2.30.0/js/msal-browser.min.js"),
   htmltools::tags$script(HTML("
 async function wrapperFunc() {
   const msalConfig = {
     auth: {
       clientId: 'XXX', authority: 'XXX' }
   };
   const msalInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
   const silentRequest = {
     scopes: ['XXX'] };
   const callLogin = async function(silentRequest, msalInstance) {
     try {
       const loginResponse = await msalInstance.loginPopup(silentRequest);
       return loginResponse;
     } catch (err) {
       console.log(err)
     }
   }
   response = callLogin(silentRequest, msalInstance);
   return response;
 }
 wrapperFunc().then(result => {Shiny.setInputValue('oauthToken', result['accessToken']);
   console.log(result['accessToken']); });"))
 )
 
/```
````